# Spring reject request that is missing vendor header (Custom MIME type)

Tags: java, spring, header, mime-types

I have the following declaration:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/vnd.woot4moo-v1+json"  

public @ResonseBody void create(String key){...}
```

This of course will take `json` but I want it to reject any request that does not contain the `vnd.woot4moo-v1` part of the header.  Is this even feasible?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the specific requests by implementing `HandlerInterceptor` as below:

**RequestMethodInterceptor class:**

```
public class RequestMethodInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor  {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        //Get the 'Accept' header value
        String headerValue = request.getHeader("Accept");

        //check the request contains expected header value
        if(!headerValue.equals("application/vnd.woot4moo-v1+json")) {
            //Reject and Log or Ignore upon your requirement & return false
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**XML Configuration:**

```
<mvc:interceptors>
      <bean class="xyz.RequestMethodInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>
```